# Error en mi configuracion de spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring, spring-security

Estoy intentando agregar una configuración de seguridad en mi web para que no se pueda entrar a las url de administración que son "/administrador/**" y "/productos/**" si no tienes el rol "ADMIN" he visto muchos tutoriales del manejo de Spring security pero todos usan WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter y por lo que veo esta obsoleta ya tengo creada mi configuración de la mejor forma que pude pero al momento de iniciar sesión me sale como no validos y no me deja entrar a las urls de administración, por lo que veo esta todo correcto no entiendo por que falla (esta es mi primera vez usando stack overflow discúlpenme si no me se explicar bien)

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/administrador/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/productos/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/carrito").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/usuario/login").permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/usuario/ingresar")
                    .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/usuario/acceder")
                    .and().build();     
 


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.info("Este es el username");
        Optional<Usuario> optionalUser=usuarioService.findByEmail(username);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            log.info("Esto es el id del usuario: {}", optionalUser.get().getId());
            session.setAttribute("idusuario", optionalUser.get().getId());
            Usuario usuario= optionalUser.get();
            return User.builder()
            .username(usuario.getEmail())
            .password(bCrypt.encode(usuario.getPassword()))
            .roles(usuario.getTipo())
            .build();
        }else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario no encontrado");           
        }
    


@PostMapping("/acceder")
    public String acceder(Usuario usuario, HttpSession session){

        Optional<Usuario> user = usuarioService.findByEmail(usuario.getEmail());

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            session.setAttribute("idusuario", user.get().getId());
            if (user.get().getTipo().equals("ADMIN")) {
                return "redirect:/productos";
            }
        }else{
            return "redirect:/usuario/registro";
        }

        return "redirect:/productos";
    }
```